# Javascript replace between string tag <strong>

Tags: javascript

i don't now how to replace this:

```
aaaDDDłłłłłaaałłłłĄąąąą<strong>
```

to

```
aaaDDDłłłłłaaałłłłĄąąąą <strong>
```

Must add one space between string a

Pseudo kod:

```
replace('string<strong> ','string <strong>');
```

Answer (score 2):

If `x` contains your string, you can replace it using *regex* like:

```
x = x.replace(/(\S+)<strong>/, "$1 <strong>");
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be at least one `\S`? Otherwise is matches if there's already a space in front.

Comment: Yeah.. Thats right. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Just like this:

```
var p = your_string.indexOf('<strong>');
if (p > 0 && p.charAt(p-1) != ' ') {
    replaced = your_string.replace('<strong>',' <strong>');
}
```

Comment: No, must be only when string is close <strong> tag

Comment: Just added new code to handle that, I try to avoid using regex for such simple cases.

Answer (score 1):

This would perform such a replacement:

```
var str = 'aaaDDDłłłłłaaałłłłĄąąąą<strong>';
str = str.replace('<strong>', ' </strong>');
```

Or, a bit more complicated:

```
str = str.replace(/(\S)(<strong>)/ig, '$1 $2');
```

Comment: No, must be only when string is close <strong> tag

Comment: @karkonosze Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sory this is good!!! Post was edit

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has had a `replace` function for strings since ECMAScript 3. It even takes a Regex and not just a normal string, so you can do some pretty powerful replacements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo code is correct

```
var str = "aaaDDDłłłłłaaałłłłĄąąąą<strong>";
var formatted = str.replace("<strong>"," <strong>");
```

`formatted` variable will now contain "`aaaDDDłłłłłaaałłłłĄąąąą <strong>`